# c++ Pass quoted string as char array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, function-pointers

So I have a function declared as:

```
void writeFile (unsigned char *fileName, unsigned char *data)
```

If I call the function like this:

```
writeFile("f.txt", "Test1");
```

is fine.

If I do a second call like this:

```
writeFile("s.txt", "Test2\nline");
```

the fileName is fine, but the data is corrupted (the first 5 bytes are messed up).

If I do a third call like this:

```
writeFile("f.txt", "Test3\r\nline");
```

the fileName is corrupted, and data has it's first 5 bytes messed up.

What is going on?

Comment: String corruption by the sound of it! ;)  Can you please show us the source for `writeFile`?

Comment: "What is going on?" Some code you haven't shown us is doing something with the strings. Could we see what `writeFile` does?

Comment: What is the body of writeFile? Do you use iostream to write on the file? And lastly, why don't you use const char*?

Comment: Side note: You left out the *"this doesn't **compile**"* from your post. This doesn't seem like real code, or if it is, you're ignoring a *lot* of warnings. You can't pass a `const char*` to a function taking a non-const `unsigned char*` as a parameter. Not without your compiler trying to reach out and slap you.

Comment: It does compile, otherwise I couldn't have test it. I posted some of the functions [here](http://pastebin.com/xCeWccfB) to give an idea.

Comment: @user1410908 the functions you posted are not *called* from anywhere, and that was my point. Your *caller* passing a `const char*` file name to `writeFile(unsigned char *fileName, unsigned char *data)` should at least throw a big fat warning in your face, and if the compiler has any decency, its an error. You shouldn't pass a `const` pointer to a function expecting a non-const parameter. In other words, the function parameter is improper (unless you plan on modifying the filename in `writeFile()`, which I highly doubt.

Comment: @WhozCraig "unless you plan on modifying the filename in `writeFile()`, which I highly doubt" I'm afraid: in the linked (pastebin) code, `writeFile(fileName, data)` calls `readFile (VERIFY, fileName)` which in turn calls `convertFileName (fileName)` which finally does `fileName[j] = fileNameFAT[j];`. Ouch.

Comment: @gx_ holy mother of.... gotta love side effects. Hope thats documented somewhere besides the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem has to do with using unsigned chars, when I put it into my code it complains on compile about it.  It may have something to do with unsigned char not being able to use escape characters like `\n`, but I can't be sure.

```
IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char *"
```

Is the compile error I get.

When I changed it to just being a regular `char *` as the parameters, it worked fine.

Comment: This is C++. If your compiler has any metal at all it should still warn you about passing a `const char*` as a `char*` parameter. But the overall direction of this idea is correct.

Comment: The file name doesn't have an escape character. Anyway, it happens even if I don't use an escape character in data.

Comment: Yes, it does warn me about passing a const char* as a char*. By the way is Atmel Studio 6.